# PHP removing everything after HTML tags

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I have a contenteditable div like this:

```
<form>
    <div name="new_post" class="post" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The contenteditable div allows **bold** and *italic* tags, but ***no other tag***.

My issue is that if the user types something like `Hello there <u>world</u>!`, it will save in the database as `Hello there`. It seems to remove everything after the tags and I don't know why.

I'm using AJAX and PHP to handle posts, so here's the rest of the code.

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($('.post').html()); // added this to debug it. This prints "Hello there &lt;u&gt;world&lt;/u&gt;!"
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/post.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize() + "&post_field=" + $('.post').html(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $post = $_POST["post_field"];

    // query to insert post into database goes here

    $array = array('message' => $post);

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Please help!

Comment: Where's the code that strips out the unwanted tags?

Comment: That's the weird part. There isn't any, yet it's removing it.

Comment: Mayble it's your web server module (like apache's mod-security)

Comment: Do you need to URL encode the HTML before concatenating it to the serialized data?

Comment: Why doesn't people never let jQuery do the serialization? Trying to outsmart jQuery never works

Comment: `data` is wrong because your `POST`ing…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.post').html()
```

to:

```
encodeURIComponent($('.post').html())
```

The HTML characters need to be encoded in a URL parameter.

Comment: This fixed my original issue, however, I now have another question. I've added `$post = strip_tags($post, "<b><i>");` to the PHP code so that it removes all tags except bold and italics. However, if the user types `Hello there <u>world</u>!` into the post box, it still outputs `Hello there <u>world</u>!`. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: New questions should be posted separately.

Comment: @Bagwell, this is done. If you bump into new issues try to fix them first by yourself before throwing 'em at SO